# How do I get a list all of my Excel Named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

Some of my Excel files have lots of Excel named ranges. How can I easily list them all in one place? The information should include things like the Name, Address, Sheet that contains it, etc.

While the Excel file is open, you can go to the Formulas area of the ribbon and select Use in Formulas in the Defined Names tab. At the very bottom is a Paste Names option. But it just gives you a list of Names and Values with no Headers. Plus, if you try to sort them by address, then you get B1, B10, B11, B2, B20, B21, B3, etc.

I found examples of VBA code on OzGrid.com and MrExcel.com, but none of them did exactly what I wanted.

In the answer below is some VBA code that will create a sheet that contains columns for the Sheet Name, Range Name, Absolute and Relative Addresses, the Column and Row and an Original Row so you can always get back to the original list after sorting. It also includes a count SubTotal formula for filtering.

Note that any named ranges that include more than one cell are skipped (e.g. Filters).

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code into a module and run it.

```
Option Explicit

' Assumes a sheet with the CodeName RangeNames.

Private Const m_CountCol As String = "A"
Private Const m_FormulaCol As String = "B"

Private Const m_SheetCol As String = "A"
Private Const m_NameCol As String = "B"
Private Const m_AbsoluteAddressCol As String = "C"
Private Const m_RelativeAddressCol As String = "D"
Private Const m_ColumnCol As String = "E"
Private Const m_RowCol As String = "F"
Private Const m_ValueCol As String = "G"
' Allows for sorting and still always being able to get back to the original order.
Private Const m_OrigRowCol As String = "H"
Private Const m_IndexCol As String = "I"

Private Sub LoadNamedRanges()
Dim lRow As Long, lEndCol As Long, lCounter As Long, lSkipped As Long, lIndex As Long, lRangeNameRow As Long
Dim sRefersTo As String, sSheet As String, sAbsoluteAddress As String, sRelativeAddress As String, sColumn As String, sMessage As String
Dim vColumns As Variant
Dim oName As Name

    ' Alternatively use the following instead.
    ' With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name")

    ' This assumes a sheet with the CodeName RangeNames
    With RangeNames
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Clear
        .Cells.EntireColumn.ClearComments
        .Cells.EntireColumn.ClearFormats
        
        ' Delete any skinny rows from prior runs.
        Call .Rows("1:1000").Delete(shift:=xlUp)
        
        lRow = 1
        .Cells(lRow, m_NameCol).Value = "Name"
        .Cells(lRow, m_SheetCol).Value = "Sheet"
        .Cells(lRow, m_AbsoluteAddressCol).Value = "Absolute Addr"
        .Cells(lRow, m_RelativeAddressCol).Value = "Relative Addr"
        .Cells(lRow, m_ColumnCol).Value = "Col"
        .Cells(lRow, m_RowCol).Value = "Row"
        .Cells(lRow, m_ValueCol).Value = "Value"
        .Cells(lRow, m_OrigRowCol).Value = "OrigRow"
        ''.Cells(lRow, m_IndexCol).Value = "Index"
        
        For Each oName In Names
            ' Skip named ranges in our Named Range sheet.
            If InStr(1, oName.Name, .Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                lSkipped = lSkipped + 1
            ' Skip named ranges that contain more than one cell (e.g. Print ranges).
            ElseIf InStr(oName.RefersTo, ":") > 0 Then
                lSkipped = lSkipped + 1
            Else
                lRow = lRow + 1
                lCounter = lCounter + 1
                sRefersTo = Replace$(Replace$(oName.RefersTo, "=", vbNullString), "'", vbNullString)
                sSheet = Left$(sRefersTo, InStr(sRefersTo, "!") - 1)
                sAbsoluteAddress = Mid$(sRefersTo, InStr(sRefersTo, "!") + 1, 1000)
                sRelativeAddress = Replace$(Mid$(sRefersTo, InStr(sRefersTo, "!") + 1, 1000), "$", vbNullString, 1, 1)
                sColumn = Left$(sRelativeAddress, InStr(sRelativeAddress, "$") - 1)
                lRangeNameRow = CLng(Mid$(sRelativeAddress, InStr(sRelativeAddress, "$") + 1, 1000))
                sRelativeAddress = Replace$(sRelativeAddress, "$", vbNullString)
                .Cells(lRow, m_NameCol).Value = oName.Name
                .Cells(lRow, m_SheetCol).Value = sSheet
                .Cells(lRow, m_AbsoluteAddressCol).Value = sAbsoluteAddress
                .Cells(lRow, m_RelativeAddressCol).Value = sRelativeAddress
                .Cells(lRow, m_ColumnCol).Value = sColumn
                .Cells(lRow, m_RowCol).Value = lRangeNameRow
                .Cells(lRow, m_ValueCol).Value = "'" & oName.Value
                .Cells(lRow, m_OrigRowCol).Value = lCounter
                ''.Cells(lRow, m_IndexCol).Value = oName.Index
                
                Call LoadColumnsArray(vColumns, sColumn)
            End If
        Next
        
        lEndCol = .Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(lRow, lEndCol)).AutoFilter
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
        ' Add a Subtotal formula for filtered counts.
        ' It will include the header column plus one additional blank row.
        lRow = lRow + 1
        .Rows(lRow).RowHeight = 3
        sAbsoluteAddress = "$B$1:$B$" & lRow
        lRow = lRow + 1
        .Cells(lRow, m_CountCol) = "Count"
        .Cells(lRow, m_CountCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Cells(lRow, m_FormulaCol).Formula = "=SubTotal(103, " & sAbsoluteAddress & ") - 1"
        .Cells(lRow, m_FormulaCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Cells(lRow, m_FormulaCol).NumberFormat = "###,###,##0"
        
        ' Insert blank row at top and copy SubTotal formula cell.
        lRow = lRow + 1
        Call .Rows(1).Insert(shift:=xlDown)
        .Cells(1, m_CountCol) = "Count"
        .Cells(1, m_CountCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Cells(1, m_FormulaCol).Formula = "=" & m_FormulaCol & lRow
        .Cells(1, m_FormulaCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Cells(1, m_FormulaCol).NumberFormat = "###,###,##0"
                
        .Activate
        .Cells(3, "A").Select
    End With
    
    With ActiveWindow
        .FreezePanes = False
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
    
    sMessage = GetMessage(lCounter, lSkipped, vColumns)
    
    Call MsgBox(sMessage, vbInformation, "Info")
    Set oName = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub LoadColumnsArray(vColumns As Variant, sColumn As String)
Dim lIndex As Long
Dim bMatched As Boolean
    If IsEmpty(vColumns) Then
        ReDim vColumns(1, 0)
        vColumns(0, 0) = sColumn
        vColumns(1, 0) = 0
    Else
        For lIndex = LBound(vColumns, 2) To UBound(vColumns, 2)
            If vColumns(0, lIndex) = sColumn Then
                bMatched = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not bMatched Then
            ReDim Preserve vColumns(1, UBound(vColumns, 2) + 1)
            vColumns(0, UBound(vColumns, 2)) = sColumn
            vColumns(1, UBound(vColumns, 2)) = 0
        End If
    End If
    vColumns(1, lIndex) = vColumns(1, lIndex) + 1
End Sub

Private Function GetMessage(lCounter As Long, lSkipped As Long, vColumns As Variant) As String
Dim lIndex As Long
Dim sMessage As String
    sMessage = "Processed " & lCounter & " named range(s)," & vbNewLine & _
                "Skipped " & lSkipped & " named range(s), " & vbNewLine
                
    For lIndex = LBound(vColumns, 2) To UBound(vColumns, 2)
        sMessage = sMessage & "Col: " & vColumns(0, lIndex) & " " & vColumns(1, lIndex) & ", " & vbNewLine
        ''Debug.Print vColumns(0, lIndex), vColumns(1, lIndex)
    Next
    
    sMessage = Trim$(sMessage)
    sMessage = Trim$(Left$(sMessage, Len(sMessage) - Len(vbNewLine)))
    sMessage = Left$(sMessage, Len(sMessage) - 1) & "."
    
    GetMessage = sMessage
End Function
```